# Python - running a script as a service with a name other than 'python'

Tags: python, executable, daemon

I have a set of `python` scripts which I run as a daemon services. These all work great, but when all the scripts are running and I use `top -u <USER>`, I see all my scripts running as `python`.

I would really like to know which script is running under which `process id`. **So is there any way to execute a `python` script as a different process name?**

I'm stuck here, and I'm not ever sure what terms to Google. :-)

Note: I'm using Ubuntu Linux. Not sure if the OS matters or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [setproctitle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setproctitle/). It should work fine on Linux.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a shot and comment back here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a linux system here to test this on appropriately, but if the above doesn't work, you should be able to use the same trick they use for things like gzip etc.

The script has to tell what to run it at the top like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Use a softlink like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python ~/bin/myutil
```

Then just change your script to

```
#!~/bin/myutil
```

and it should show up that way instead. You may need to use a hard link instead of a soft link.

Launching a python script using the python script itself (and file associations and/or shell magic) is not very portable, but you can use similar methods on nearly any OS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this is using [she bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). The first line of your python script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

depending upon whether you use python or python3

and then assign executable permissions to the script as follows:

```
chmod +x <scriptname>
```

and then run the script as

```
./scriptname
```

this will show up as `scriptname` in `top`.